# delete brush not working in windows

Tags: windows, graphics

I have an old style Windows API program with a home made layer in C++ on top of it. So I create a brush to paint with, and in the destructor call DestructObject(Handle) to release it. For many brushes this does not seem to work. I have to release the brush manually before calling the destructor, or the program will halt.

Why is this so? My explanation is that I have too many open brushes for Windows. Is the delete operator in a separate thread delaying the call to DestructObject?

Comment: There is not `DestructObject` API so it must be your own implementation and we can't guess what's inside. Or maybe you meant `DeleteObject`, but still we can't help you if we don't know how you use it. Besides, how do you know that it doesn't work?

Comment: I am sorry. I meant DeleteObject(Handle). I am calling this in SolidBrush::~SolidBrush of my brush class, which should be initiated by the delete operator. I admit, that I could have done a check if and when Windows really does the DeleteObject, but it would not be easy. The reason is that it fails only with hundreds of objects. And you cannot access the object after the delete. I know that it works if you wait between the actions. I fixed it by calling DeleteObject (setting the Handle to 0) before I delete the object (checking for a 0 handle there).

Comment: You haven't answered how do you know that deleting doesn't work - I don't see any proof that it is 'not working'. Real code is much more useful then textual description of it.

Comment: Forget it. It is impossible to post hundreds of lines here.